# CURLOPT_PROXY does not have effect on PHP >= 5.5?

Tags: php, curl

Weird issue.

This code does not seem to have effect on PHP >= 5.5, works fine on PHP < 5.5 though

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, "173.240.15.XXX:808");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "user-001:abc123456");
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, because it's driving me crazy !

Comment: I doubt it very much. If `CURLOPT_PROXY` support were removed, they surely would have documented such a major incompatible change.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference, but maybe try using `CUROPT_PROXYPORT` instead of putting the port number in `CURLOPT_PROXY`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using apache mod_proxy
because squid in this scenario is ok

try remove curl_setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, true)
if your php version >= 5.5